DepthLab objects to place
How can I generate objects to place in DepthLab for Android like the Robochef by default? Are there any examples I can get somewhere else?
I try to use DepthLab for a demo.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This code is in a public git repo: https://github.com/googlesamples/arcore-depth-lab and the only image to pace (robochef) is here: https://github.com/googlesamples/arcore-depth-lab/tree/8f76532d4a67311463ecad6b88b3f815c6cf1eea/Assets/ARRealismDemos/AvatarLocomotion/Models/Robochef              Thanks in advanced!!
